# Как запустить приложение, написанное на c++ на другом компьютере

Tags: c++, mingw

Чтоб развлечься взялся писать программку, которая бы по достижению определенной громкости выключала компьютер. Для работы со звуком используется portaudio, собранный из исходников под minGW. Само приложение тоже собирается minGW64, в QTCreator, на винде и под винду. У меня на компе стартует без проблем, на другом компе сначала просил пачку dll (libgcc_s_seh-1, libstdc++-6, libwinpthread-1), после того как их подложил, стал выдавать ошибку "0xc000007b". На конечный комп накатан Dx, .NET и MSVC(все что есть). Что еще можно сделать и куда посмотреть?
Если нужно ознакомится с кодом - прилагаю
https://github.com/ff00000000X00/TT

Comment: Значит незватает зависимостей, скопированы не все dll или не те dll.

Comment: А че делать-то?

Comment: Копируйте *нужные* зависимости.

Comment: Надо же, почему-то пока здесь вопрос не задал, на ум не пришло взять dll'ки из папки с minGW64. Магия stackoverflow, не иначе. Спасибо за комментарий, он меня толкнул куда надо